# link to play html code rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this rails link

```
<%= link_to c.title, course_url(c) %>
```

[guitar course](http://mydomain.com/es/mycourse)

I'm getting a link generated.

I would like get the html like a text instead of link:

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/es/mycourse">guitar course</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= link_to(c.title, course_url(c)).to_str %>
```

Calling `to_str` makes generated string unsafe, so it's automatically escaped by Rails.

Comment: I'm checking with this and it does not works for me. I'm getting the link generated again! Thanks!